# SQL Server 2008 notifications

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

C#, VS 2005, SQL Server 2008

I have a database on a remote server. It has a table **table1**. Several clients work with it. Each client can change the content of **table1**. Each client must represent actual content of this table. So I need some algorithm to make sure the clients always represent the most current content of **table1**.

I know that SQL Server 2008 supports a notification mechanism (reporting services). How can I use it for my task ?

Comment: How many clients? That type of push isn't necessarily scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cache invalidation mechanism around Query Notification. With QN each client builds a cache of its view of table1 and receives a notification when it's view of the data is stale and needs to be refreshed. See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for more details how this works. In your C# project this boils down to properly leveraging the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class.